# How can i add '"-" in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

my query is showing in row 2000 the data of 2000-2001 & in 2001 the data of 2001-2002.
how can i change the column so that it displayes

```
column 1        column 2
2000-2001         5
2001-2002         3
2002-2003         9
2003-2004         12
.
.
.
.
```

and so on...

Comment: I realy don't understand, what do you want to do :/.

Comment: Can you post your current code.

Comment: What does it show at the moment? In column one, does it show -1 instead of 2000-2001, 2001-2002 and so on?

Comment: I believe this is what he's trying to achieve. In this first question, he was provided with an answer, and this question is looking to get a working solution to the answer he was given:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067910/sql-query-calculating-no-of-employees-joined-each-financial-year-i-e-from-1-04-20

Comment: I posted a solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067910/sql-query-calculating-no-of-employees-joined-each-financial-year-i-e-from-1-04-20/3069804#3069804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your query this will have to be very generic, but something like the following should work:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(col1) || '-' || TO_CHAR(col1+1) as "column 1",
       col2 as "column 2"
  FROM (SELECT col1,
               SUM(col2) as col2
          FROM sometable
          WHERE something = something_else
          GROUP BY col1)
```

The above is Oracle syntax (the TO_CHAR and || string concatenations) but should give you a good idea of how to proceed.

EDIT: In SQL Server try the following:

```
SELECT CAST(col1 AS NVARCHAR(100)) + N'-' +
                                    CAST(col1+1 AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS "column 1",
       col2 as "column 2"
  FROM (SELECT col1,
               SUM(col2) as col2
          FROM sometable
          WHERE something = something_else
          GROUP BY col1)
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: If you could post the query you're currently using we might be able to offer more assistance.

Comment: jasmeet, if it doesn't solve the problem, please explain why it doesn't. What do you expect? And what do you have so far?